# Instagram in-app browser not loading images

Tags: image, instagram, inappbrowser

I really hate the instagram in-app browser. It displays things different than almost all normal browsers. For some reason, my images wont load.

My website links to images in other websites. But these images have no extensions. (not sure if this is the issue)

```
<img src="http://example.com/b53cbe2d745bm96nmwwfgcz7v6i215">
```

These images won't load in the instagram in-app browser. But in all other browsers, the images load no problem.

Also, my site is https while the images are http. Not sure if this makes a difference.

Is there a way to test my site in the instagram in-app browser?

**ALL OTHER BROWSERS**
[image]

**INSTAGRAM IN-APP BROWSER**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your images are insecure, when your site is secure, browser blocked mixed content